# Can't bind to tree since it isn't a known property of tree

Tags: tree, angular5

I'm trying to use ng2-tree and run into an error that >

**ERROR**

```
Can't bind to 'tree' since it isn't a known property of 'tree'. ("
            </tbody>

            <tree [ERROR ->][tree]="tree" *ngIf="tree" >
                <ng-template let-node >
                    <span clas"): ng:///EditFolderModule/FolderPathComponent.html@16:18
'tree' is not a known element:
1. If 'tree' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. To allow any element add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component.
```

**folder-path.html**

```
<tree [tree]="folderTree" *ngIf="folderTree" >
      <ng-template let-node >
         <span class="node-name" [innerHTML]="node.name"></span>
      </ng-template>
</tree>
```

**folder-path.module.ts**

```
public tree: TreeModel = {
        value: 'Programming languages by programming paradigm',
        children: [
            {
                value: 'Object-oriented programming',
                children: [{ value: 'Java' }, { value: 'C++' }, { value: 'C#' }]
            }
        ]
    };
```

I've tried a few examples on this site, but no luck:

https://github.com/angular-ui-tree/angular-ui-tree

Comment: How does your `app.module` look like?

Comment: There is an `edit-folder.module.ts`, I imported `folder-path.module.ts` to there and then imported `edit-folder.module.ts` to `app.module.ts`

Comment: Where do you import your `TreeModule` ?

Comment: in `folder-path.module.ts`